Guidance on Using HSM-Generated Code Signing Certificates on Virtual Machines with Developer RDP Access
I am planning to purchase a code signing certificate and understand that recent updates to the process now require the private key to be generated by a Hardware Security Module (HSM). I need assistance on how to obtain a code signing certificate that can be used on a virtual machine, enabling developers to sign code via RDP access to the VM. Additionally, can Azure Vaults be leveraged for this purpose?
The tools our team uses for code signing include:
* Excel's option to add a digital signature.
* Osslsigncode for command-line signing.
* InstallShield, which has a similar manual certificate addition option like Excel.

